# How to ask GCC for the configured PATH_SEPARATOR?

Tags: gcc, gnu-make

I want to use the environment variable CPATH for compiling my application with GCC. The GCC manual says that the list of paths assigned to CPATH must be separated by the special character PATH_SEPARATOR, which got defined when GCC was build. PATH_SEPARATOR is usually ';' on Windows and ':' elsewhere.

Since I want to build my code on multiple platforms I need to know the character PATH_SEPARATOR in my makefile (to concatenate the paths assigned to CPATH correctly).

Can I ask my used GCC, with which value for PATH_SEPARATOR it was build?

(Of course I can alternatively try to detect the host OS in GNU make, and speculate on a suitable path separator from there, but this is not exactly the same. (E.g. I expect unwanted problems with CygWin))

Comment: But you don't care about the PATH_SEPARATOR of the platform gcc was built *on*, or *for* (these need not be the same). You care about PATH_SEPARATOR of the target platform (need not be the same as either of the above).

Comment: I need to know the PATH_SEPARATOR of the platform gcc was built *for*. I don't want to know the path-separator of my current platform. (Imaging a GCC build for Windows but called from Cygwin) So basically I want to know, which path separator GCC accepts inside CPATH.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm saying? Anyway, I don't think gcc knows anything about PATH_SEPARATOR on your target platform. It may or may not have any notion of path. Does a controller in your mucrowave have paths? Gcc has no idea.

Comment: There seems to be different understandings what "for" means here. If I understand you correct, you meant the target platform on which the code runs which gets compiled with my gcc. However I meant the host OS for which gcc itself was compiled to run on. 

E.g. You can have a GCC compiled on Linux as a native Windows application, which runs then under Cygwin on Windows to compile code for an ARM micro-controller.
In this case I am interested in the separator of native Windows.

Comment: PATH_SEPARATOR is a macro set in the "Host Configuration Headers" when building gcc itself. So a particular gcc knows which path separator it accepts. The question is: Can I ask my gcc, which separator it accepts (in the environment variables which control the compiling by my gcc)?

Comment: On my machine it's defined in `/usr/lib/gcc/<platform>/<version>/plugin/include/system.h`

Comment: OK got why you want it, sorry about the confusion.